# converted particles on top of one another instead of simulation position (warning: contains bacon)

Tags: particles, instances, dupli-groups

Got some bacon problems.

I'm trying to fill a bag of bacon cubes and things were going well until was time to convert my particles.

I've gather 6 different pieces of bacon in a collection;
my bacon pieces are active collision and rigid bodies, applied transformations, each with it's origin set to geometry;
[image: bacon]

created a rigid body container with a transparent material and collision physics, displayed as Bounds only;
[image: bag]

then I've set a particle system to a plane as emissor;
set to Render As Collection;
set the Instance Collection as my BACON collection;
[image: Physics tab]

alright, about frame 50 the container is pretty much filled as airtight packed bacon is supposed to look, so it's time to convert the bacon mayhemness in a mesh I can edit, shrinkwrap another mesh around it to make the 'real' container etc.

[image: lots of bacon!]

but then, when I convert it, all the 3174 pieces of bacon are sent to the same point, one on top of another. things go awry and I can't get my beautiful packed bacon.

[image: don't go there, stay here]

the blue selection is all the bacon that was supposed to be in the bacon pack, as in the simulation.

here's the bacon looking like bacon, so ya'll feel motivated to help me! haha

[image: pretty bacon]

** i'm taking suggestions on how to fill a container with bacon; i'd love to convert all the bacon to mesh, do some cleanup and use it, even if it's over 3k pieces, I was guessing that I could clean it up somehow and use it. i know it's a lot of bacon, but the container wouldn't fill up sooner. lots of trial and error on this part. taking advices!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up trying to use hair particles on the container and after a ton of fiddling with the settings, got the bacon on the layout I wanted. things were awkward with the hair particles, as they were displaced on some kind of natural vortex (i say natural because there was no force field applied, and the bacon-hair was growing on a spiral pattern. then i copied one of the sides of the container and applied hair on it, so the sides wouldn't be emitting bacon.

after some more fiddling, i could convert all the particles to meshes. a ton of meshes, btw, 5k+. so i did some cleaning, and some more cleaning, and some more, and was happy with around 600 pieces.

then, i joined 'em all, shrinkwrapped my container on it, gave it some offset, applied the label on a set of the container duplicated faces and voilà!

[image: vieport cycles render]